# Yocto:Could not inherit file classes/autotools-brokensep.bbclass

Tags: yocto, bitbake, pandaboard

I am new to yocto project. I am getting the following error while running the bitbake command

```
$bitbake gemini-image

ERROR: ParseError at /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/meta-ivi/meta-ivi/recipes-extended/persistence-client-library/persistence-client-library_git.bb:18: Could not inherit file classes/autotools-brokensep.bbclass
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

my bblayers.conf file is

```
# LAYER_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
LCONF_VERSION = "6"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/poky/meta \
  /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/meta-ivi/meta-ivi \
  /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/meta-ti \
  "
BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= " \
  /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/poky/meta \
  /home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/poky/meta-yocto \
```

And my local.conf file is(edited lines only)

```
MACHINE?= ”pandaboard”
DISTRO ?= "poky-ivi-systemd"
INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE = "GPLv3"
```

any one familiar with these types of errors??
please feel free to ask if any further details is needed to understand the problem

EDIT:
This is the persistence-client-library_git.bb file

```
SUMMARY = "GENIVI Persistence Client Library"
DESCRIPTION = "The Persistence Management is responsible to handle \
persistent data, including all data read and modified often during \
a lifetime of an infotainment system."
HOMEPAGE = "http://projects.genivi.org/persistence-client-library"
BUGTRACKER = "http://bugs.genivi.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Persistence"
LICENSE = "MPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=6161c6840f21a000e9b52af81d2ca823"

DEPENDS = "dlt-daemon dbus libcheck persistence-common-object"

PV = "7.0+git${SRCPV}"

SRC_URI = "git://git.projects.genivi.org/persistence/persistence-client-library.git"
SRCREV  = "441b3ce710ec6b7f1e6360cdf29e5c4243af9f1e"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig autotools-brokensep

PARALLEL_MAKE = ""

FILES_${PN} = " \
   ${libdir}/*.so \
   ${libdir}/*.so.* \
   ${sysconfdir} \
"

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/dbus-1/system.d
    install -m 0644 ${S}/config/org.genivi.persistence.admin.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/dbus-1/system.d
}

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "node-state-manager"
```

Comment: Please post this file: 
/home/zappy/Desktop/fyocto/meta-ivi/meta-ivi/recipes-extended/persistence-client-library/persistence-client-library_git.bb

Comment: Which versions (revisions) of poky (meta and meta-yocto) as well as meta-ivi are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Problem: It is not able to locate the `autotools-brokensep.bbclass` which is mentioned in your `persistence-client-library_git.bb` as `inherit pkgconfig autotools-brokensep`

Solution: Provide the path of the file in `bblayers.conf` where the file locates, and even check th layers.conf of which the file resides.

Comment: Thank you ... @Dilip Kumar .. there was no file named autotools-brokensep.bbclass under my poky/metaClasses/  directory.  I manually downloaded the file and copied there. that fixed the error. but here comes a new error....                                                                                             No recipes available for:
  /home/rajeesh/Desktop/fyocto/meta-ivi/meta-ivi/recipes-connectivity/bluez5/bluez5_%.bbappend      ..............

Comment: @zappy this is new error you need to debug based on the recipies available and what other files its expecting.

Comment: @zappy You'll need to ensure that you're using the correct version of poky as required by meta-ivi. You're having a mismatch between branches and versions.

Comment: @Anders  But i am following this [this](http://wiki.projects.genivi.org/index.php/Meta-ivi/5.0.0) to select version.please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @zappy No, you're not following the instructions in that link, at least not to the letter... The persistence-client-library recipe in the 5.0 branch do not inherit autotools-brokensep, it inherits the regular autotools class. This is done as it's based on the dora release of Poky, which didn't separate the build directory from the source directory. I'm guessing that you might have the dora branch of Poky, but the master branch of meta-ti. You shouldn't need to copy files to the meta layer in order to get out to build.